# How to set by default selected values in PrimeNg MultiSelect with Angular 4 Reactive Form?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, primeng-dropdowns

I am using MultiSelect control from PrimeNg ([PrimeNg Multiselect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect)) & Angular4 with a Reactive Form, and I want to keep some my items default selected during form loading.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <span translate>settings.account.webhook.label.additional.variables</span>
      <p-multiSelect [options]="sensorsList" (onChange)="changeSensorsList($event)"
            formControlName="selectedSensorsList" name="selectedSensorsList" [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'20em'}"></p-multiSelect>
</div>
```

**Here is my TypeScript code**

```
sensorsList = [
    { label: 'lat', value: {'id': 0, 'itemName': 'lat', 'selected': false }},
    { label: 'lng', value: {'id': 1, 'itemName': 'lng' , 'selected': false}},
    { label: 'address', value: {'id': 2, 'itemName': 'address' , 'selected': false}},
    { label: 'origin', value: {'id': 3, 'itemName': 'origin' , 'selected': false}}
  ];

 this.addEditWebhookForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      name: [(_webhookToEdit) ? _webhookToEdit['name'] : '', [Validators.required]],
      selectedSensorsList: []
 });
```

Comment: You can set the default value to your formControlName

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide value for your `selectedSensorsList` when you create the `formGroup`:

```
 this.addEditWebhookForm = this._formBuilder.group({
     ...,
     selectedSensorsList: [
         defaulSensorsList
     ]
 });
```

or set the value later:

`this._formBuilder.get('selectedSensorsList').setValue(defaultSenorsList);`

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

You need to set a ngModel in your primeng component

```
<div class="col-md-4">
          <span translate>settings.account.webhook.label.additional.variables</span>
          <p-multiSelect [options]="sensorsList" (onChange)="changeSensorsList($event)"
                formControlName="selectedSensorsList" name="selectedSensorsList" [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'20em'}"  [(ngModel)]="selectedDefault"></p-multiSelect>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
selectedDefault= [];
sensorsList.map((item) => selectedDefault.push(item.value));
```

Right here I'm selecting all of them.

You will also have to udpate the sensorlist object to changed the value selected to true

Comment: Of course you can pass to the array the ones you want to be selected by default

Comment: We are not supposed to use formControlName and ngModel on a same component

Answer (score -1):

You have to set default option with in ngOnInit

```
selectedSensorsList: [{'id': 0, 'itemName': 'lat'}]
```